# How safe is protocol activation? How can i ensure security when launching a Windows Store 8.1 app from a desktop app using protocol activation?

Tags: security, windows-store-apps, protocols, windows-store, activation

I must launch the Windows Store 8.1 app from a desktop application. I came across the concept of protocol activation where the user can launch the store app using the protocol name and pass parameters to the store app from desktop application. Is it safe to launch this way? if i can implement some security mechanism(security token) to secure the communication, how do i go about it?

Answer (score 2):

Protocol activation is not safe per se. 
The thing is the calling app can never be sure which application registered for a certain protocol on the system. Therefore the "evil twin" problem exists: An app could pretend to be the expected application for a certain protocol but in fact isn't. E.g. I could write an app and register as "spotify" or "facebook" or "bing" and could try to steal the passed parameters.

It depends on what kind of hazard you are trying to avoid. The best option is to not pass sensitive data with the protocol launcher . Instead pass only data that only the true target application can "translate" into sensitive data. (e.g. an encrypted ID)

On target application side it's the same thing: The called application can not be sure who's the caller. It can not be validated or restricted.

Both changes with AppLaunchers for Windows 10: You can specify the package family name of the target application and you can whitelist the calling application with Windows 10.